# Access and change arbitrary scene frame values

Tags: python

Apparently in older versions of Blender, I could run code like this:

```
 bpy.data.scenes.frame_set(10)
```

When I try to run it in Blender 2.93, it requires that I include ['Scene'] when changing the frame.

[image]

Is there any way I can change the frame in Blender 2.93 regardless of which scene I am in?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK `bpy.data.scenes.frame_set(10)` has never been available.  One wonders if the answer here is simply `bpy.context.scene.frame_set(20)` to change frame on scene that has context.

Comment: @batFINGER Yeah, that was what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

*I can't find any [global call to set the frame](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_70_release/search.html?q=frame_set&check_keywords=yes&area=default) for all scenes in older API versions.*

If you'd like to set the frame for all scenes, just iterate through the scenes in your blend and set the frame. Recommend use the [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html) to figure out:

```
>>> D.scenes
<bpy_collection[1], BlendDataScenes>

>>> for s in D.scenes:
        s.frame_set(23)
```

If you'd like to set the frame for a specific scene which is currently not the active one, get a reference of the actual scene using pythons `get()` and call [`Scene.frame_set()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Scene.html?highlight=frame_set#bpy.types.Scene.frame_set) on that reference:

```
import bpy

scn = bpy.data.scenes.get("Scene")
if scn:
    scn.frame_set(23)
```

In case you'd like to set the frame for multiple known scenes at once: I'd suggest create a list, set or tuple out of scene names and iterate through the items beforehand:

```
import bpy

for s in ('Scene', 'Scene.001', 'Scene.002'):
    scn = bpy.data.scenes.get(s)
    if scn:
        scn.frame_set(23)
```

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer to my rather simple quesiton. batFINGER made a comment on my original question and what he suggested is what solved it for me.

Comment: No problem. Based on your provided code (`D.scenes`) in combination with your question `regardless of which scene I am in?`, I did assume that you want to set the frame of a specific scene rather than the active scene. If your q is to set the frame for the current scene (`C.scene`), I voted to close as dupe to keep the site organized @AnsonSavage

Answer (score 1):

You have access to the scene `frame_current` property and you can also set it like below:

```
# for example if want to set 23 as current:
import bpy
bpy.context.scene.frame_current = 23
```

And if you want to set for all scenes you should do through a for loop:

```
import bpy
for sc in bpy.data.scenes:
    sc.frame_current = 23
```

Comment: Assigning a value to `Scene.frame_current` property won't *update the scene*, it moves the cursor in the timeline though.

Comment: @brockmann but for me it updates an animated scene. either through `context.scene` or through for loop on `data`. it even updates all armatures and skinned meshes.

Comment: Yeah, I should have said: it won't update *properly*, e.g. try to render 2 frames using the render operator and set the current frame as you do here, you'll see that not all properties of the objects are updated *properly*: https://pasteall.org/Dfwn There are a lot of Q&As here as well dealing with this issue.